# Convert separated string with comma to some object in java

Tags: java, string, object

I have array of string like : `String [] contact={"val1","val2","val3","phone1","phone2","phone3"};`

I want to convert it to myClass and it looks like:

```
Class myClass{
   String val1;
   String val2;
   String val3;
   Phones phones;
}

Class Phones{
   String phone1;
   int phone2;
   int phone3;
}
```

My problem that some of the string values may be empty, like:

```
String[] contact={"val1","val2"," ","phone1","",""};
```

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: show the code you are using to assign

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to write a "constructor", a method with the class name as its name, taking a String[], that assigns values to the field computed from the parameter it got.